# How render object in React Router?

Tags: reactjs

I have an array in a react component state.

Each array element is supposed to be a `li` element.

How can we render this?

```
 this.state = {
  main: 'Main', about: 'About', contacts: 'Contacts', '404': 404
}
```

Comment: does this solve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Two suggestions -:

1. You need to add a state variable to store this data.
2. Once this is done your state will be something like this.

   this.state = {
     data: [{main: 'Main', about: 'About', contacts: 'Contacts', '404': 404}]
   }

Once the state has a data variable which is an array, we can

```
render(){
    return (
        <ul>{this.state.data.map(item => <li>{item.main}</li>)}</ul>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is better to put your pages name in an array like this:

```
 this.state = {
  pages:['Main',  'About',  'Contacts', '404']
}
```

and now you can put everyone of this pages as a path in `Route` tag using react-router like this:

```
renderRoutes(){
   return this.state.pages.map(item=>{
      return <Route path={item}/> 
})
}
```

I hope it was helpful. If it is please vote me up:)